# Haskell: infinite lists - how lazy is Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How lazy is Haskell?

Why does the following not know when to stop?

```
sum ([n^2 | n <- [1..], odd (n^2), n^2 < 100])
```

Answer (score 12):

This isn't about how lazy it is, but rather whether there is any way it can possibly know that `n^2 < 100` will never be true again once it was false once. Which it doesn't.

These parts of an array comprehension are *filter expressions*, not *stop conditions*.

Comment: And the property depends on the types too.  Imagine a ring where `x^2 > 100` but `(succ x)^2 < 100` - the first filtered element does not imply there would be no more filtered elements for all types.

Comment: Indeed, and given that there are no type annotations, it's probably possibly to instantiate this expression to a type that is `Num` and represents unsigned integers modulo say 512.

Answer (score 7):

Just because 11^2 is more than 100 doesn't mean 13^2 is more than 100. Well... okay, it does, but how is GHC supposed to figure that out? It's a compiler, not a prover of arbitrary mathematical truths.

Comment: Among other somewhat magical properties users seem to think a functional compiler has over common compilers... automatic memoization, arbitrary partial evaluation, algebraic rewriting...

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson to be fair, haskell enthusiasts do love to praise GHC for being hella smart, so I can see where this comes from.

Answer (score 2):

The expression you've given effectively desugars into:

```hs
sum $ do
    n <- [1..]
    _ <- if odd (n^2) then [()] else []
    _ <- if n^2 < 100 then [()] else []
    return (n^2)
```

If you have never seen the List monad then this probably seems like a weird way to use `do` but it turns ultimately into:

```hs
sum $ concatMap (\n -> if odd (n^2) && (n^2 < 100) then [n^2] else []) [1..]
```

where `concatMap` is in the Prelude (in earlier versions you can define it as `(concat .) . map` but now it applies to any `Foldable`, not just lists, and is therefore closer to `(concat .) . fmap`).

Now the key thing here is that when Haskell sees this function it stops analyzing! It is a theorem of computer science that the only general way to prove properties about arbitrary general functions is to run them -- Haskell does not peek inside, and does not give `concatMap` any way to peek inside, a function to try to determine if it will eventually yield `[]` for all further inputs!

Computers are **dumb**, and that is **good**: the smarter a program is, the harder it is to model it in your head. `concatMap` is a very dumb function, it just applies its function-argument to every element of the list and puts them all together with `concat`, and that's all it does. List comprehensions are a very dumb syntax replacement for the `do` notation of the list monad, that's all they do. The `do` notation is just a very dumb syntax replacement for the function `>>=` in the `Monad` typeclass, which for lists is `concatMap`. Because all of these things are very dumb, you can understand everything that goes on very easily.