# Minimal Purely Applicative Parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, applicative

I'm trying to figure out how to build a "purely applicative parser" based on a simple [parser](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html) implementation. The parser would not use monads in its implementation. I asked this question previously but mis-framed it so I'm trying again.

Here is the basic type and its `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Alternative` implementations:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a,String)] }

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Parser cs) = Parser (\s -> [(f a, b) | (a, b) <- cs s])

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure = Parser (\s -> [(a,s)])
  (Parser cs1) <*> (Parser cs2) = Parser (\s -> [(f a, s2) | (f, s1) <- cs1 s, (a, s2) <- cs2 s1])

instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = Parser $ \s -> []
  p <|> q = Parser $ \s ->
    case parse p s of
      [] -> parse q s
      r  -> r
```

The `item` function takes a character off the stream:

```
item :: Parser Char
item = Parser $ \s ->
  case s of
   [] -> []
   (c:cs) -> [(c,cs)]
```

At this point, I want to implement `digit`. I can of course do this:

```
digit = Parser $ \s ->
  case s of
    [] -> []
    (c:cs) -> if isDigit c then [(c, cs)] else []
```

but I'm replicating the code of `item`. I'd like to implement `digit` based on `item`.

How do I go about implementing `digit`, using `item` to take a character off the stream and then checking to see if the character is a digit without bringing monadic concepts into the implementation?

Comment: I'd say this seems to require monads. You can workaround the problem by generalizing digit to arbitrary predicates e.g. `sat :: (Char->Bool) -> Parser Char`. I'm pretty sure you were not asking for that, though... :-)

Comment: @chi Thanks. Can you explain why this requires monads? I'd like to learn how to identify whether it needs to use monads or not.

Comment: Even better for a purely applicative parser (actually alternative): `newtype Parser a = Parser {run :: forall f. Alternative f => (Char -> f a) -> f a}` (you can do it with `Applicative`, but `Alternative` allows choice).

Comment: @PyRulez Can you elaborate? I don't see how that implementation would look.

Comment: @PyRulez I somehow assumed changing the type was disallowed, without no particular reason. Your type looks intriguing... you could expand it into a proper answer?

Comment: @chi That won't help solve this. I just saying that it is more of a "pure applicative functor" than the current type.

Comment: @Ana My intuition is that without monads, the _control_ of the computation is statically determined. E.g., if IO were an applicative but not a monad, we could not ask for input and, depending on that, performing some output. Even `getLine >>= putStrLn` can not be done with applicatives only. Here you want the parser to fail whenever the "input" is not a digit, and I'm guessing this is impossible to do reusing `item`.

Comment: @chi and Ana https://gist.github.com/ChristopherKing42/cb30809332ccb9d7a6bd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us write down all the tools we currently have at hand:

```
-- Data constructor
Parser :: (String -> [(a, String)]) -> Parser a

-- field accessor
parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]

-- instances, replace 'f' by 'Parser'
fmap  :: Functor f     =>   (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
pure  :: Applicative f =>                 a -> f a

-- the parser at hand
item :: Parser Char

-- the parser we want to write with item
digit :: Parser Char
digit = magic item

-- ?
magic :: Parser Char -> Parser Char
```

The real question at hand is "what is `magic`"? There are only so many things we can use. Its type indicates `fmap`, but we can rule that out. All we can provide is some function `a -> b`, but there is no `f :: Char -> Char` that makes `fmap f` indicate a failure.

What about `(<*>)`, can this help? Well, again, the answer is no. The only thing we can do here is to take the `(a -> b)` out of the context and apply it; whatever that means in the context of the given `Applicative`. We can rule `pure` out.

The problem is that we need to check the `Char` that `item` might parse *and* change the context. We need something like `Char -> Parser Char`

But we didn't rule `Parser` or `parse` out!

```
magic p = Parser $ \s ->
  case parse p s of -- < item will be used here
    [(c, cs)] -> if isDigit c then [(c, cs)] else []
    _         -> []
```

Yes, I know, it's duplicate code, but now it's using `item`. It's using `item` before inspecting the character. That's the only way we can use `item` here. And now, there is some kind of sequence implied: `item` has to succeed before `digit` can do it's work.

Alternatively, we could have tried this way:

```
digit' c :: Char -> Parser Char
digit' c = if isDigit c then pure c else empty
```

But then `fmap digit' item` would have the type `Parser (Parser Char)`, which can only get collapsed with a join-like function. That's why [monads are more powerful than applicative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34932624/1139697).

That being said, you can get around all of the monad requirements if you use a more general function first:

```
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy = Parser $ \s -> 
   case s of
     (c:cs) | p c -> [(c, cs)]
     _            -> []
```

You can then define both `item` and `digit` in terms of `satisfy`:

```
item  = satisfy (const True)
digit = satisfy isDigit
```

That way `digit` does not have to inspect the result of a previous parser.

Answer (score 2):

Functors allow you to act on somethings values. For example, if you have a list `[1,2,3]`, you can change the contents. Note that Functors do not allow changing **structure**. `map` can not change the length of a list.

Applicatives allow you to combine structure, and the content is mushed together somehow. **But the values can not change influence the structure**.

Namely, given an `item`, we can change its structure, and we can change its content, but the content can not change the structure. We can't choose to fail on some content and not other.

If anyone knows how to state this more formally and provably, I'm all ears (it probably has to do with free theorems).

Comment: As chi said, interested in seeing the expanded implementation. Perhaps you would give an alternative implementation in your answer based on the type you provided.

Comment: @Ana It simply isn't possible with Applicative. (I did post my implementation in the comments, which also contains a monad based one in the comments.)

Comment: @Ana Tell me if you have any questions about it (or add a comment directly to the gist.)

Comment: @Ana Here is the monad implementation: https://gist.github.com/ChristopherKing42/cb30809332ccb9d7a6bd#file-interestingparsertype-hs-L24

Comment: @Ana Actually, this is the link: https://gist.github.com/ChristopherKing42/cb30809332ccb9d7a6bd/52ef0a575838e25d556fe174b73bdb3571771647#file-interestingparsertype-hs-L29

Comment: @Ana It can only be "used" by converting it into other parser types, I think? (You could convert it into a state monad probably.)

Comment: I'd really like to understand how that implementation can be used. If I post your code as a separate question, would you expand it into a full answer with example?

Comment: @Ana Sure, since it doesn't really answer this question, and comments are awkward.