# Purely Applicative Parser using Alternative

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative, higher-rank-types, alternative-functor

In a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639893/minimal-purely-applicative-parser), a user offered an implementation of a purely applicative parser for Haskell (code originally from [here](https://gist.github.com/ChristopherKing42/cb30809332ccb9d7a6bd)). Below is the partial implementation of that parser:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

import Control.Applicative (Alternative(..))
import Data.Foldable (asum, traverse_)
```

The type:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser {run :: forall f. Alternative f => (Char -> f ()) -> f a}
```

The instances:

```
instance Functor Parser where
    fmap f (Parser cont) = Parser $ \char -> f <$> cont char

instance Applicative Parser where
    pure a = Parser $ \char -> pure a
    (Parser contf) <*> (Parser cont) = Parser $ \char -> (contf char) <*> (cont char)

instance Alternative Parser where
    empty = Parser $ \char -> empty
    (Parser cont) <|> (Parser cont') = Parser $ \char -> (cont char) <|> (cont' char)
    some (Parser cont) = Parser $ \char -> some $ cont char
    many (Parser cont) = Parser $ \char -> many $ cont char
```

Some example parsers:

```
item = Parser $ \char -> asum $ map (\c -> c <$ char c) ['A'..'z']
digit = Parser $ \char -> asum $ map (\c -> c <$ char (head $ show c)) [0..9]
string s = Parser $ \char -> traverse_ char s
```

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time trying to understand how I might use this parser implementation. In particular, I do not understand what `Char -> f ()` should/could be and how I could use this to do simple parsing, e.g. to extra a digit out of an input string. I'd like a concrete example if possible. Could someone please shed some light?

Comment: Doesn't the end of the gist you linked to give two examples of what `f` could be?

Comment: "In particular, I do not understand what Char -> f () should/could be" - it isn't *just* `Char -> f ()`, it is `forall f . Alternative f => (Char -> f ()) -> f a`. You cannot consider "something" of type `Char -> f()` in isolation here - you must consider the entire function at once (because of the universal quantification). You can view this `Parser` as a least upper bound of all (alternative) parsers - it doesn't implement any functionality, instead it relies on the semantics of whichever type `f` is eventually instantiated to.

Answer (score 2):

In `forall f. Alternative f => (Char -> f ()) -> f a`, the `Char -> f ()` is something that you are *provided* with. Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to then turn that into an `f a` using only these two bits:

- The `Char -> f ()` function (i.e. a way to parse a single character: if the next character matches the argument, the parsing succeeds; otherwise it doesn't.)
- The `Alternative` instance of `f`

So how would you parse a single digit into an `Int`? It would have to be of the form

```
digit :: Parser Int
digit = Parser $ \parseChar -> _
```

In `_`, we have to create an `f Int` using the kit `parseChar :: Char -> f ()` and `Alternative f`. We know how to parse a single `'0'` character: `parseChar '0'` succeds iff the next character is `'0'`. We can turn it into a value of `Int` via `f`'s `Functor` instance, arriving at

```
digit0 :: Parser Int
digit0 = Parser $ \parseChar -> fmap (const 0) (parseChar '0')
```

But `f` is not just `Functor`, it is also `Alternative`, so we can write `digit` in long-form as

```
digit :: Parser Int
digit = Parser $ \parseChar -> fmap (const 0) (parseChar '0') <|>
                               fmap (const 1) (parseChar '1') <|>  
                               fmap (const 2) (parseChar '2') <|>  
                               fmap (const 3) (parseChar '3') <|>  
                               fmap (const 4) (parseChar '4') <|>  
                               fmap (const 5) (parseChar '5') <|>  
                               fmap (const 6) (parseChar '6') <|>  
                               fmap (const 7) (parseChar '7') <|>  
                               fmap (const 8) (parseChar '8') <|>  
                               fmap (const 9) (parseChar '9')
```

And from here, it is merely a matter of pedestrian Haskell programming to cut down on the cruft, arriving at something like

```
digit :: Parser Int
digit = Parser $ \parseChar -> asum [fmap (const d) (parseChar c) | d <- [0..9], let [c] = show d]
```

which we can further simplify by noting that `fmap (const x) f` can be written as `x <$ f`, giving

```
digit :: Parser Int
digit = Parser $ \parseChar -> asum [d <$ parseChar c | d <- [0..9], let [c] = show d]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Char -> f ()` part represents matching on a single character. Namely, if you do `char 'c'`, it will match on `'c'` and fail on everything else.

To use it, you can convert it to, say Parsec:

```
convert :: Parser a -> Parsec a
convert p = run p anyChar
```

`p` is essentially of the type `forall f. Alternative f => (Char -> f ()) -> f a`, which specializes to `(Char -> Parsec ()) -> Parsec a`. We pass in `anyChar`, and it will produce a `Parsec a` value by using `anyChar` and any `Alternative` operations.

Basically, a `Parser a` it is a function that, given away to match on a single character, and an `Alternative` instance, it will produce an `Alternative` value.